# Long-running jobs in an event-driven environment with constrained max-execution-duration

Tags: async, event, rabbitmq

Hello we have an async event-driven system (kotlin, spring cloud stream, rabbitmq) where there might be an event `FooPayloadArrived`, published by an ingress rest-controller.
Processing this `FooPayloadArrived` and publishing the follow-up result in a subscribe may take some time, let's say 1h.

Being in AWS and using a managed RabbitMQ via the AWS MQ service, [we are constrained in the maximum execution of any such message](https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumers.html#acknowledgement-timeout): After 30 minutes (AWS just decided on this new max and you cannot change this setting either....) the message/event currently being processed is basically aborted and requeued, aborting any long-running event-subscriber and restarting it (because message/event is requeued automatically) - so we are in an endless aborted-after-30-minutes loop.

We are currently very much in favour of the event-driven async mode of processing anything, since any failure puts your failed event into a dead-letter-queue (DLQ) which allows you to simply retry the operation after you fixed something. We don't want to abandon this resilience feature for long-running jobs.

Is there some alternative pattern how to design running those jobs vs. the enforced timebox?

Comment: whats the exact 30min limit you are referring to? seems really odd

Comment: https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumers.html#acknowledgement-timeout
this is enforced by AWS MQ and you cannot (currently) change it

Answer (score 1):

Your event handler could copy the message to an "in-progress" queue (IPQ) or database table and confirm reception of the message to the MQ service before processing the message.

When the message was processed successfully, it needs to be removed from the IPQ, and the next message is read from the MQ service.

Note that the IPQ needs to be treated similarly to the DLQ in that you need to handle messages from this queue when the main event handler did not process them successfully. To do this correctly, you must be able to determine safely whether the message is indeed still in progress or the event handler crashed.

Comment: this basically means we use different processing of IPQ-messages that is not constrained by the timeout-constraints? would not know how do so actually